# how can i send variables in link with json ? i make filter to data with different var like name & country

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

i use json to filter my data ..

i'm making search form to filter my data and i'm using php & mysql

i search with name & country & age

but data shows in div and i can't make pagination with php because variables doesn't sent over url ...

i want url appears like localhost/rootfolder/search?country=uk&name=carla&age=23

```
function get_site_data(){

filter_url = '';

if($("#nickName").val()) { var nick = $("#nickName").val(); }
else var nick = '';                 
if (nick != '' && nick != '-') 
if(filter_url == '')
filter_url += ' full_name like "'+nick+'%"';
            else
filter_url += ' And full_name like "'+nick+'%"';

                                        if($("#country").val()) { var country = $("#country").val(); }
    else var country = '';                  
    if (country != '' && country != '-') 
    if(filter_url == '')
    filter_url += ' country = "'+country+'"';
        else
        filter_url += ' And country = "'+country+'"';
```

and i send data with

```
`if (filter_url=="")
{
document.getElementById("member_user").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("member_user").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?q="+filter_url,true);
xmlhttp.send();         
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit confusing question, but a few tips:

- for ajax, use one of the popular JS libraries/frameworks, like jQuery, prototype, or backbone
- don't assemble your mysql query in javascript, just pass variables to your php and assemble the query there
- check out examples of the JS framework you choose, to see how to generate answers in php, and update your html with them